# How do I get the value of a text field using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-forms

I want to get the value of a text field value using AngularJS when a form is submitted.

The code below always shows "undefined".

html:

```
<form ng-submit="AdvanceSearchSubmit($event)" name="AdvanceSearch" novalidate>
 <p ng-show="!AdvanceSearch.SearchKeyWord.$pristine && AdvanceSearch.SearchKeyWord.$invalid" class="text-danger">Text Cannot Be Empty!</p>
  <div ng-hide="AdvanceSearchModel" class="input-group">
    <input name="SearchKeyWord" ng-model="SearchKeyWord" id="SearchKeyWord" class="form-control" placeholder="Search in timeline...." type="text" required>
      <span class="input-group-btn" ng-click="isAdvanceSearch='false'; SearchPost(0,'true')">
       <button ng-disabled="AdvanceSearch.$invalid" type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
       </button>
      </span>
     </div>
</form>
```

one attempt:

```
$scope.AdvanceSearchSubmit = function(event)
{
    alert(event.target.value);
};
```

another attempt:

```
$scope.AdvanceSearchSubmit = function(event)
{
    alert(event.SearchKeyWord.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `event` pass the `SearchKeyWord` as a parameter

```
ng-submit="AdvanceSearchSubmit(SearchKeyWord)"
```

controller

```
$scope.AdvanceSearchSubmit = function(keyWord)
{
    alert(keyWord);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the event at all to your `AdvanceSearchSubmit` on submit. You already have your values available inside `$scope` like `ng-model` for input field like `ng-model="SearchKeyWord"`

```
alert($scope.SearchKeyWord); //access value from `$scope` directly
```

Comment: why event.SearchKeyWord.value is not working can you explain please????

Comment: @nayanchowdhury I'm not saying it isn't possible, you can retrieve form values by doing `console.log($(event.target).serializeArray())` inside your function. But there is no need of doing that at all, AngularJS provides you awesome databinding feature that keeps track of your model and updates values whenever user change the values. Better you should pass your `model` to `submit` method and send that data to API..